# How to update a docking corner?

Tags: c++, qt

I am making a application by Qt, that has a central widget, right dock widget and left dock widget. Their sizes are fixed.

They are displayed, but there a blank space between the central widget and the right widget when the left dock widget is floating.
https://twitter.com/#!/hizz_GI/status/155768124321435648/photo/1

Will you please tell me the way to remove the blank space?

I appreciate you taking the time to respond to my question.

code:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    textEdit = new QTextEdit;
    textEdit->setFixedSize(100, 150);
    setCentralWidget(textEdit);

    creatDocks();
    layout()->setSizeConstraint(QLayout::SetFixedSize);
}

void MainWindow::creatDocks()
{
    leftTextEdit = new QTextEdit;
    rightTextEdit = new QTextEdit;

    leftDock = new QDockWidget(tr("Left Dock Widget"));
    rightDock = new QDockWidget(tr("Right Dock Widget"));

    leftDock->setFixedSize(100, 150);
    leftDock->setAllowedAreas(Qt::LeftDockWidgetArea | Qt::RightDockWidgetArea);
    leftDock->setWidget(leftTextEdit);

    rightDock->setFixedSize(150, 150);
    rightDock->setAllowedAreas(Qt::LeftDockWidgetArea | Qt::RightDockWidgetArea);
    rightDock->setWidget(rightTextEdit);

    addDockWidget(Qt::LeftDockWidgetArea, leftDock);
    addDockWidget(Qt::RightDockWidgetArea, rightDock);
}
```

I found a solving.
It is a way that calls menuWidget()->adjustSize() and adjustSize() when paintEvent of MainWindow without textEdit->setFixedSize() and layout()->setSizeConstraint().
But it is expensive. What time is the proper call?
And is this appropriate?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, since you set all the 3 widget to have a fixed size, when your left widget is floating, the central widget correctly go to the left, but since it and the right widget have a fixed size, they where not resized to fill the space in the middle.

Have you the same problem also when the central or right widget are floating instead of the left widget ?

Comment: Thank you, Gianluca. 
No problem when the right widget is floating instead of the left widget.
https://twitter.com/#!/hizz_GI/status/155789289832185857/photo/1